# HTML/CSS/Javascript -- Transitions and drawing

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'd like to know how to do these slick transitions (the drawing of lines and moving of images). It be great if one could tell me what it's called, and what it takes to do it, i.e. css, javascript, jquery, or a combination of all of them, or even frameworks.  I'm sorry I have to ask this but i literally have no idea what to call it.

[onlycoin](https://onlycoin.com/),
[polygon](http://www.polygon.com/a/ps4-review)

Comment: Look at http://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_2dtransforms.asp

Comment: the "view source" on the second link is somewhat revealing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are quite a few ways of going about doing this, and because there is no built-in/standard way of doing what you want, then here are a few handy scripts: [Raphael.js](http://raphaeljs.com/) and

For a method with just javascript and some CSS, [here's](http://jsfiddle.net/Tdggh/) one I found that uses some math to check for the line. 
Here's the JSFiddle code:

```
var top = 0;
var left= 0;
var top2 = 0;
var left2 = 0;

$("#draw").css("background", "gray")
    //Check if even or not
    i = 0;
    $("#draw").on("click", function(e) {
       i++;
    //If even, draw line
        if (i%2 != 0) {
        //First point
        top = e.pageY
        left = e.pageX
        }
        else  {
        //Second point
        top2 = e.pageY
        left2 = e.pageX
        //Calculate difference
        heightdifference = top2-top;
        widthdifference = left2-left;
            //arcsin fix: x < -1 or x > 1 not allowed
            //I suck at this, maybe someone can find a better solution?
            divide =  (heightdifference/widthdifference < -1 || heightdifference/widthdifference > 1) ?  widthdifference/heightdifference : heightdifference/widthdifference
            //Rotate the line
        rotation = 180/Math.PI*Math.asin(divide)
            //Pythagoras
        width = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(heightdifference,2)+Math.pow(widthdifference,2))
            //Margin: Pythagoras 2
        a = width/2
        var b
        c = widthdifference/2
        margintop = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(a,2)-Math.pow(c,2))
            margintop = (rotation > 0) ? 0-margintop : margintop            
        $("<div>").css({
           "height": "2px",
           "background": "black",
           "width": width,
           "position": "absolute",
           "top": top,
           "left": left,
            "margin-top": 0-margintop,
            "-webkit-transform": "rotate("+rotation+"deg)",
            "-moz-transform": "rotate("+rotation+"deg)",
            "-ms-transform": "rotate("+rotation+"deg)",
            "-o-transform": "rotate("+rotation+"deg)",
            "transform": "rotate("+rotation+"deg)"

        }).appendTo("#draw")
        }           
    })
```

There is also a helpful tutorial [here](http://arc.id.au/JsAnimation.html) for animation with JavaScript.

Sorry I couldn't help much, but hopefully this will point you in the right direction.